# How to add right margin to searchView's searchIcon?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-search

How can I add right margin to the searchview's searchicon? I can't seem to find any working options here.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/main_searchView"
                        app:defaultQueryHint="@string/search_titel"

                        android:paddingLeft="6.0dp"
                        android:paddingRight="6.0dp"
                        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                        android:maxWidth="1000000dp"
                        android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"

                        />
```

Comment: put layout.xml here

Comment: it's a normal searchview. Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
```

it can also be solved using this i think:

```
LinearLayout searchEditFrame = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_frame);
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) searchEditFrame.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = 0;
```

Comment: Hey. I  need a margin between the searchicon and the search text. Your answer just adds margin to the searchedit frame. Thanks anyways.